# Check if a filename without extension exists

Tags: vba, vbscript

I have the file name with the entire path of the file except the file extension.

Example: `"C:\temp\FileNameWithoutExtension"`. Now I want to check if this file exists? I don't care about the file extension.

When I have the entire file name including file extension I was using following code to see if the file exists.

```
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
FileExists = oFSO.FileExists(FileName)
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: For now I decided to loop through all the files in the parent directory and do something like InStr("C:\temp\FileNameWithoutExtension.txt","C:\temp\FileNameWithoutExtension") > 0 to see if the file exists, but I am wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be nice if FileExists handled wildcards but it does not. Would something like this help?

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\temp")
Set objFiles = objFolder.Files

For Each objSingleFile in objFiles
    If objSingleFile.Name Like "FileNameWithoutExtension*" Then
        ' The file name starts with FileNameWithoutExtension
        MsgBox "Are you looking for me?: " & objSingleFile.Name
    End If
Next
```

This is making assumption about the location you are searching and it is not recusrive but the basics are here for you to look at. This is not the only approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub FileExist()
    Dim file As String, fileName As String
    fileName = "C:\temp\abc" & "*"
    file = Dir(fileName)

    If file = "" Then
        MsgBox "File doesn't exist"
    Else
        MsgBox "file found"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I like your idea but I am getting the error "Variable is undefined: 'Dir'"